# image is not rendering in react native

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to fetch an image url , it also print it successfully in console but practically it is not rendering.

**Note:** The height and width also successfully prints in console but it is not rendering.
Please this below code.

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    imgLink: '',
     };
    };

    fetchData = data => {
       var foo = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
       this.setState({imgLink: foo});
       this.setState({height: 
       data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.height});
       this.setState({width:  
       data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.width});
        }


        render(){
         return(
          <Image
           style={{
           width:width,
           height:height,
           alignItems:'center',
           borderRadius:50 ,
           marginLeft:'auto',
           marginRight: 'auto',
           marginTop: 40,
           }}
           resizeMethod = "resize"
           onError={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.error) }
           source={{uri: this.props.imgLink }}/>
           );
           }
```

Comment: You need to access `width` and `height` from state: `width: this.state.width,` and `height: this.state.height,`.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

On your `<Image` methods for width and height you are using `width` and `height` with no previous declarations.

---

### Solution

Modify your `<Image` methods of `width` and `height` to use values from the component state as below:

```
<Image
    style={{
        width: this.state.width,
        height: this.state.height,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        marginTop: 40,
    }}
    resizeMethod="resize"
    onError={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.error)}
    source={{ uri: this.props.imgLink }} />
```

---

### Bonus

You don't need to call thi.setState() multiple times.
You can modify your fetchData function like so:

```
fetchData = data => {
    var foo = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
    this.setState({
        imgLink: foo,
        width: data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.width,
        height: data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.height
    });
}
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: but bro i already set this width and height as let{width,height} = this.state after writing render() . That is why i am not using this.state . Now solve the problem bro.

Comment: can you please post your complete code so its easier to see everything